# How to totally disable selinux on android 12 when build with lineageos 19.1?

Tags: android, lineageos

build an image with lineageos 19.1
selinux policy is somewhat too difficult to me
so is there a way to totally disable (not permissive) selinux when compile the image?

i did some search
and permissive is not expected
how to totally disable selinux?